# If $-k$ is an eigenvalue of a $k-$regular graph $G$, then $G$ is bipartite

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, discrete-mathematics, graph-theory

I'm trying to show that, for $G$ a $k$-regular graph with adjacency matrix $A,$ if $-k$ is an eigenvalue of $A$, then $G$ must be bipartite.

What I know: Since $G$ is $k-$regular, $k$ is an eigenvalue of $G.$ Furthermore, if $G$ is not bipartite, it has at least one cycle of odd length $m$. Then we should have that $\text{trace}(A^{m}) > 0.$ For $\{\lambda_{i}\}_{1}^{n}$ the eigenvalues of $A, \text{trace}(A^{m}) = \sum_{i}^{n}{\lambda_{i}^{m}} = (-k)^{m} + \lambda_{2}^{m} + ... + \lambda_{n-1}^{m} + (k)^{m} = \lambda_{2}^{m} + ... + \lambda_{n-1}^{m}.$ But I'm not sure how to now show that the rest of these eigenvalues will also sum to $0$. Any direction?

Comment: I think the simplest method is just using the definition. What might be the eigenvector for the eigenvalue $-k$? Consider its largest coordinate and see what happens.

Comment: @radekzak Hi, thanks for the suggestion. I've found the eigenvector to always have entries of 1, -1, and 0 for such an adjacency matrix, so the largest coordinate is 1, but I'm not sure what you mean by using the definition...

Comment: This can't be true – if $v$ is an eigenvector, so is $2v$.